# Possible to change locale in PHP?

Tags: plugin-development, localization, ajax

I've got a plugin which is defaulting to English during AJAX calls, but I need it to stick to whatever the current language is. I can send the current locale through via AJAX data, but I'm not sure how to change the locale in PHP.

It's possible to get the current locale like this...

```
craft()->getLanguage()
```

Is there a way to **set** the current locale in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I got this resolved the *proper* way... looks like you just need to **make sure that your AJAX calls are localized.**

In my main `_layout` template:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
window.siteUrl = "{{ siteUrl }}";
</script>
```

Then in my JS, I have this:

```javascript
$.post(
    siteUrl + 'actions/myPlugin/myAction',
    ...
);
```

As long as your `siteUrl` is being localized properly, it should trickle down into the JS... and the localized AJAX path can then load a properly localized template.

Comment: Just to make sure i understood what you ment, if I'm using example.com/en & example.com/fr I should do the ajax request to those actual urls instead of example.com?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Include the `en` or `fr` in the AJAX URL.

Answer (score 2):

In a project I'm currently using `define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'nl_be');` inside index.php to set it based on the request URI.

I imagine this should also work by getting a parameter from the request and setting it based on that.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! My understanding is that this only works within the context of the `index.php` file, but I'll give it a quick try and report back.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. The controller action ignored the `define`, and just fell back to English. Thanks anyway!